# Quiero que dependiendo de la ruta en react se muestre un menu diferente

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-navigation

Tengo el siguiente codigo de un enrutamiento en react

```
<div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <GeneralProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
        <Route path="tienda">
          <Route path="" element={<TiendaIndex />} />
          <Route path="productos">
            <Route path=":id" element={<ProductoSolo />} />
          </Route>
          {window.innerWidth <= 400 ? <Route element={<MobileMenu />} /> : null}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </GeneralProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

lo que pasa es que no se muestra el elemento MobileMenu, quiero que ese menu se muestre solo en pantallas menores a 400px, pero aparte solo cuando se este en la ruta tienda, llevo bastante tiempo sin encontrar informacion si alguien puede ayudarme gracias